# Unclear where bash output is going

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, stdout

I made a small script to output the list of vim plugin remotes to a file, so I could figure out what ones I want to keep or remove. However, when I run it, the output doesn't get piped to the file. Everything else works as it should. What did I do wrong here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
HERE=$(pwd)
for D in $HOME/.vim/plugged/*/; do
    if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
        cd "$D" || git remote -v >> "$HERE/vim-plug-remotes.txt";
    fi;
done
cd "$HERE" || exit
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cd "$D" || ...
```

is change directory OR do this other thing, which means if the `cd` succeeds (which it should), `git` will not be run.

```
cd "$D" && git ...
```

would be more typical for cd-and-do-this-thing. (`bash -x` is handy for debugging this sort of thing).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want `&&`, not `||` -- `||` is a logical *or*, `git` will only run if `cd` failed.

Change:

```
cd "$D" || git remote -v >> "$HERE/vim-plug-remotes.txt";
```

to (although the semicolon is unnecessary):

```
cd "$D" && git remote -v >> "$HERE/vim-plug-remotes.txt";
```